# How to validate the length of nested items in a serializer?

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

I am using Django Rest Framework 2.4.
In an API where I am expecting a dictionary containing two keys:

```
{
  "category" : <category-id>,
  "items" : [{"title": <title>}, {"title": <title>}, {"title": <title>}, ....]
}
```

I have a `ItemListSerializer` that accepts this dictionary. category is a foreign key to the Category model hence we get that data. category has a limit property which

I have a list of items which is handled by a nested ItemSerializer with many set to True

However, I want to check if the total number of items don't cross the limit which is based upon the category ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use [validate()](http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/serializers/#validation) method on the serializer to check the length and raise `ValidationError` if it doesn't pass:

```
class YourSerializer(serializers.Serializer):
      items = ItemSerializer(many=True)

      def validate(self, attrs):
           if len(attrs['items']) > YOUR_MAX:
               raise serializers.ValidationError("Invalid number of items")
```

Comment: Will the validate() method get called prior to the validation of nested items serializers ?

Comment: @AmoghTalpallikar, I don't think so. That would be very strange though. The child must be valid prior to parent's validation.

Comment: That's a problem in my case, because then there is a place where I will be validating each item based upon it's index. if index more than the category expects, it could be a problem and if I raise validationerrors after checking the index at each point, I will have errors for each item.

Comment: @AmoghTalpallikar, The only place you have access to both `category` and `items` for validation is where I described above. I'm using the same thing and it works perfectly. If there is any problem with `ItemSerializer` then you won't even get that far.

Answer (score 5):

You can create a [validate_items()](http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/serializers/#field-level-validation)

Django rest framework will display the error as a field error for that field. so parsing the response will be easier

```
class YourSerializer(serializers.Serializer):
    items = ItemSerializer(many=True)

    def validate_items(self, items):
        if len(items) > YOUR_MAX:
            raise serializers.ValidationError("Invalid number of items")
```